# Scan of groups using RegEx

Tags: regex, elixir

The return for the following code is not at all what I expected:

```
iex(12)> Regex.scan(%r/(?<groupname>a)b(c)/g,"abcdabcd", capture: :groups)
[["a"], ["a"]]
```

There are 2 groups, but only the named one appears in the result. And also the groupname is completely ignored.

If I use named_capture, I get the following:

```
iex(14)> Regex.named_captures(%r/(?<groupname>a)b(c)/g,"abcdabcd", capture: :groups)
[groupname: "a"]
```

---

Well, I think the result of

```
Regex.scan(%r/(?<groupname>a)b(c)/g,"abcdabcd", capture: :groups)
```

should be either

```
[["a", "c"], ["a", "c"]]    #=> including "anonymous groups"
```

or

```
[[groupname: "a"], [groupname: "a"]] #=> include group name in the results
```

So my question is why do I have to name groups in group captures when using Regex.scan just so they are completely ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens the name `:groups` is misleading. It is not meant to be all groups but only the named ones. That's why [we are renaming `:groups` to `:named` in upcoming releases](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/2051). You can get the behaviour you want by using `capture: :all_but_first`. I will be documenting this option shortly.

Comment: Yep, `capture: :all_but_first` works like a charm. But why is it called `all_but_first`?

Comment: The default mode is `:all`, which captures the whole match plus each capture (anonymous or named). `:all_but_first` excludes the whole match.